# Generics, inheritance - TypeVar bound class fails mypy check

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, mypy

hope i won't leave out anything important. My very much simplified situation is like this:

In my domain I have some defined data structures:

```
@dataclass
class Model:
    var_1: str
    var_2: str

class Book(Model):
    ...

class Page(Model):
    ...
```

I want to have 2 abstraction steps defining how the data is processed, like :

```
PARAMETERS = TypeVar("PARAMETERS", bound=Model)
RESULT = TypeVar("RESULT", bound=Model)


class Finder(Generic[PARAMETERS, RESULT], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def run(self, parameters_dict: Dict[str, str]) -> RESULT:
        parameters = self.parse_parameters(parameters_dict)
        return self.do_stuff(parameters)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def parse_parameters(self, parameters_dict: Dict[str, str]) -> PARAMETERS:
        ...

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self, parameters: PARAMETERS) -> RESULT:
        ...


BookParameter = TypeVar("BookParameter", bound=Book)
BookResult = TypeVar("BookResult", bound=Page)


class BookFinder(Generic[BookParameter, BookResult], Finder[BookParameter, BookResult], abc.ABC):
    def parse_parameters(self, parameters_dict: Dict[str, str]) -> BookParameter:
        return Book(**parameters_dict)

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def do_stuff(self, parameters: BookParameter) -> BookResult:
        ...
```

and then use it like:

```
class ItalianBookFinder(BookFinder[Book, Page]):
    def do_stuff(self, parameters: Book) -> Page:
        # define this

class LatinBook(Book):
    var_3: str
    
class LatinBookFinder(BookFinder[LatinBook, Page]):
    def parse_parameters(self, parameters_dict: Dict[str, str]) -> LatinBook:
        # define both this
    
    def do_stuff(self, parameters: LatinBook) -> Page:
        # and this too


class EnglishPageFinder(PageFinder[EnglishPage, PageFinderResult]):
    ....
```

(i'm omitting the `RESULT` part, but is similar to `PARAMETERS`, too long text already)

But when i run mypy check on my code i get the error:

```
Incompatible return value type (got "Book", expected "BookParameter")  [return-value]
```

which leads me to think i am not doing this correctly. i might be totally missing some important part, or have design flaw in here, if anyone knows i'll be happy for any input.
Thank you.

Comment: Basically you say: given a subclass `SomeFinder(BookFinder[SomeBook, SomePage])` (where `SomeBook` and `SomePage` are subtypes of `Book` and `Page`), `SomeFinder.parse_parameters` should return a [non-strict] `SomePage` subtype. That isn't true, because inherited `BookFinder.parse_parameters` returns a `Book`, not a `SomeBook`. You shouldn't provide an implementation (make `BookFinder.parse_parameters` an abstractmethod) to be type-safe.

Comment: @SUTerliakov . I see, thank you. So I wanted to do incorrect thing. Would it make sense to add `parameter_factory: Type[PARAMETERS]` on `Finder`, and then when defining `ItalianBookFinder[BookFinder[Book, Page]]` set `ItalianBookFinder.parameter_factory=Book` ?

Comment: That's a cool idea, if you have it reused or wrapped with additional logic, IMO (e.g. having `parse_parameters(self, params): return self.factory(**params)` if the factory isn't used in other places is needlessly abstract, IMO, but if there are many "implementations" differing in factory only - OK too). In general - *it depends*, but probably yes.

Comment: @SUTerliakov, thanks!  there are many implementations with same factory, very few with different -> the need to have the option to change the factory + nice to not having to implement `parse_parameters` over and over.
I'm quite happy with that. should i close the question? Or make a concise response and close it then?

Comment: Self-answering questions is great, please post your final solution so that it might help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the comment by SUTerliakov, i wanted to do something wrong. In order to not do that incorrect thing but having the behavior as similar as possible i ended up changing the main abstract class a bit:

```
class Finder(Generic[PARAMETERS, RESULT], metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def parameters_type(self) -> Type[PARAMETERS]:
        ...

    def parse_parameters(self, parameters_dict: Dict[str, str]) -> PARAMETERS:
        return self.parameters_type(**parameters_dict)
```

and then adding the `parameters_type` to the last class in my sequence.

```
class ItalianBookFinder(BookFinder[Book, Page]):
    parameters_type: Type[Book] = Book           

    def do_stuff(self, parameters: Book) -> Page:
        # define this
```

this seems to work and does exactly what i wanted, adds only 1 extra line so i am quite happy to go with it.